# JSF merge multiple iterators in trinidad

Tags: html, jsf, iteration, trinidad

In my JSF page I'm running on 2 diffrent iterators

using tr:iterator tag.

each iterator print 3 words

The html that generated from this page contains 2 'dt'  elements which contains the 3 words in 3 other 'td' element.

Is it possible the the html which generated will include 6 'td' elements at one list?

so that the elements from the first iterator will not differ from the elements from the second one.

I need something like Append Tag that is used to append iterators to form an appended iterator

through which the entries goes from one iterator to another after each respective iterator is

exhausted of entries.

my code:

```
   <tr:panelHorizontalLayout > 
       <tr:iterator value="#{bean.x}" var="x" rows="0" > 
          <tr:outputText value="#{x.a} "/>           
       </tr:iterator>   
       <tr:iterator value="#{secondbean.y}" var="y" rows="0" > 
          <tr:outputText value="#   {y.b} "/> 
       </tr:iterator>    
   </tr:panelHorizontalLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does the "tr" namespace come from? The default iterator of JSF is ui:repeat. You'll have to provide more information and some code to get help with this.

Comment: tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"

Comment: @RasmusFranke , I updated my question and added sample code.

Comment: You should add your code to your original question rather than in a comment, to make it readable, and also add a "trinidad" tag to your question to find the right kind of people to answer it :).

Comment: @john: As long as I've been on Stack Overflow, I've never seen someone who seems to be knowledgeable enough about Trinidad. In other words, the community support for Trinidad is extremely low here. Have you tried their own forum/mailinglist? A lot of answers on the [Trinidad tag here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trinidad) are mostly either self-answers or not exclusively related to Trinidad.

Comment: That said, from your description, this possibility seems very unlikely, if you want something like that you'll most likely have to code it in the managed beans.

Answer (score 0):

The [`tr:panelHorizontalLayout`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_panelHorizontalLayout.html) is a layout element that arranges its children horizontally.
Since [`tr:iterator`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_iterator.html) is a naming container element, both `tr:iterator`'s will be the children that will be arranged by the `tr:panelHorizontalLayout`.

Try replacing `tr:iterator` with [`tr:forEach`](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_forEach.html).